# SortedList indexed by something other than the Key

Tags: c#

I want an indexed list by ID, ordered by a special attribute inside my class.

SortedList, doesnt do this, because it forces me to sort by the key...

Lets say my class is

```
class example{
 int Id;
 int Order
}
```

Is there any structure that is indexed like a dictionary, and ordered by something else?

so that I can access data by ID, but in a foreach the data is ordered by Order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no `Dictionary` type object that will give you that behavior right out of the box.

If you are only worried about accessing in a specified order in a `foreach` loop then why not use `LINQ`?

```
SortedList<int, example> sortedList = new SortedList<int, example>();
... //populate list

var sortedByOrder = from kp in sortedList
                    orderby kp.Value.Order
                    select kp;

foreach (var kp in sortedByOrder)
{
    ... //access will be ordered by example.Order
}
```

Yes you will pay a penalty in performance, but if it is not an issue this is, IMHO, the easiest way to get what you want.

Comment: as I only add the items once, I used your solution

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is nothing provided as standard that will provide ordering based on values, but still provide O(1) lookup like a dictionary. However writing something that can do this is fairly simple:

```
public class SortedLookup<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<TValue>
{
  private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _lookup;
  private readonly IComparer<TValue> _comparer;

  public SortedLookup(IComparer<TValue> comparer)
  {
    _lookup = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    _comparer = comparer;
  }

  public TValue this[TKey key] 
  {
    get { return _lookup[key]; }
    set { _lookup[key] = value; }
  }

  public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator()
  {
    return _lookup.Values.OrderBy(v => v, _comparer).GetEnumerator();
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the collection has to be ordered at any time, then a hybrid collection consisting of an ordered collection and a dictionary might be a solution.

My Solution only implements `ICollection<TValue>`, however you might want to implement other interfaces or individual methods as well.

```
public class SortedKeydCollection<TKey, TOrder, TValue> : ICollection<TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    private SortedList<TOrder, TValue> _list = new SortedList<TOrder, TValue>();
    Func<TValue, TKey> _keySelector;
    Func<TValue, TOrder> _orderSelector;

    public SortedKeydCollection(Func<TValue, TKey> keySelector, Func<TValue, TOrder> orderSelector)
    {
        _keySelector = keySelector;
        _orderSelector = orderSelector;
    }

    #region ICollection<TValue> Members

    public void Add(TValue item)
    {
        _dict[_keySelector(item)] = item;
        _list[_orderSelector(item)] = item;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _dict.Clear();
        _list.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(TValue item)
    {
        return _dict.ContainsKey(_keySelector(item));
    }

    public void CopyTo(TValue[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        int i = arrayIndex;
        foreach (TValue item in _list.Values) {
            if (i >= array.Length) {
                break;
            }
            array[i++] = item;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _list.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TOrder, TValue>>)_list).IsReadOnly ||
                   ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dict).IsReadOnly;
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(TValue item)
    {
        bool res1 = _list.Remove(_orderSelector(item));
        bool res2 =  _dict.Remove(_keySelector(item));
        return res1 && res2;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<TValue> Members

    public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note that the key and order selectors have to be specified in the constructor

```
var collection = new SortedKeydCollection<int, int, example>(x => x.Id, x => x.Order);
```